# How do I access the Request object from RazorViewEngine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, request

I have subclassed `RazorViewEngine` so I can check for `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` and add a special mobile identifier to the view file name for it to grab. However I can't access the `Request` object. What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use either the `HttpContext.Current.Request` or `Context.Request`. Although understand how that `IsMobileDevice` works. It uses a browser file which contains a list of known user agents. As soon as a new device is built, that list is outdated, but in some cases may still identify the device to be mobile correctly. The recommended way is to use [51Degrees](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) or to connect to the services it encompasses directly.

Comment: It is a bad practice to perform any logic in the View.The best place is the controller.